# Start call on Cisco Voip phone with an http link

Tags: voip, call

I don't have any previous experience with IP phones.
I'd like to know if there is a way to make a call with a Cisco IP Phone  (model 7912) clicking just a web link. Actually the phone is connected to the PC and the user can call using their web-based contact directory. We built a website (in the vpn) and want to do the same but using some link or script (do exist something like http://phoneip/callxyz?).